# I can't execute Electron in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian

I installed Electron on my device, but when I call it using command line and I type `electron` or `electron --version` then this error comes up :

```
[13888:0902/090414.973855:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

Also `chrome-sandbox` is owned by root I made sure of that. However I don't know how to find out about its mode number. I've been searching in Google and other websites but I couldn't find any solution to solve this issue and start working with Electron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the mode of the file by running

```
chmod 4755 /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
```

as root (or with `sudo`).

To see the current mode, run

```
stat /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
```

and look at the “Access” line — this will show the mode in both octal format (four octal digits as used in the error message) and symbolic format (as used in `ls -l`’s output).

Comment: How does that binary get there? How can we trust something in node_modules/ folder to have suid root on our dev machines? This seems like a security nightmare.

Comment: @Gardner following the upstream [installation instructions](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/installation#global-installation): `npm install electron -g`. Once you’ve installed anything from a given repository as root, it doesn’t make much difference if anything from that repository is suid root or not, you’ve already given up the keys to the kingdom (if the repository is compromised or its contents aren’t vetted).

Comment: I don't want to install a binary via npm and then give it suid root. Files that come from npm cannot be trusted. Your comment seems to lack understanding of my question. When you link to the npm installation istructions it makes me wonder if you understand the security implications that I am referring to.

Comment: @Gardner I’m commenting based on the context in the original question, not yours (since I didn’t know it). The OP installed Electron as root; that was already a done deal. I don’t recommend that either but that wasn’t really the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Stephen.